# How to render the new action of another controller with ajax/jquery in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I would like to know how to render the new action of another controller with ajax/jquery in rails 3.

Lets say i have a Clients and a Sales controller, model and view, what i would like to do is to be able to make a new sale from the clients index view using ajax/jquery.

For this i have a button next to each client named "New Sale", when its clicked it should render the form to make a new sale for that client.

What i was thinking is that it could be done either rendering the new_sale form from the Sales controller or rendering a new sale form created inside the Clients views folder and create a new action inside the Clients controller to create a new sale, though im not sure if that could be done.

Anyway i would like to know how to approach to render that new sale form, any thoughts?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT **
Here is my code:

```
#clients index.html.erb
#I couldnt make work the link like you suggested so i did it like this
<%= link_to "Venta", { :controller => "sales", remote: true, :action => "new", :cliente_id => cliente.id, :class => 'btn btn-small btn-primary', :id => 'btn-venta-clientes-index'} %>

#Div where i want to render the new sale form
<div id="test" class="modal-body"></div>


#new.js.erb inside sales views folder, i tried with the 3 of them one at a time but none work
#$("div#test").html("<%= escape_javascript(j render :partial => "form") %>"); 
#$('div#test').html('<%= escape_javascript(render("form")) %>');
$('div#test').html('<%= j render :partial => "form" %>');


#Sales controller
#I tried removing all formats from the new action but didnt work
def new
  @sale = Sale.new
  @cliente = Cliente.find(params[:cliente_id])

  respond_to do |format|
    #format.html # new.html.erb
    #format.json { render json: @sale }
format.js
  end
end

#I tried removing all formats from the create action but didnt work
def create 
  @sale = Sale.new(params[:sale])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @sale.save
     #format.html { redirect_to @sale, notice: 'Sale was successfully created.' }
     #format.json { render json: @sale, status: :created, location: @sale }
 format.js  { render action: "create" }
    else
     #format.html { render action: "new" }
     #format.json { render json: @sale.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
 format.js  { render action: "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

Do you know what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sketched roughly your situation with a solution that I made​​. Maybe something is not optimal, something is wrong, but I hope you will understand the general idea better than by words:

```
#clients/index.haml
= render @clients


#clients/_client.haml
.client-container
  %p= client.name 
  ...
  .form-container{ :id => "client-#{client.id}" }
    = link_to "New sale", new_sale_path(:client_id => client.id), :remote => true

#SalesController
def new
  @sale = Sale.new
  @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
end

#sales/new.js.erb
$("#client-<%= @client.id %>").html("<%= j render :partial => "form" %>");

#sales/_form.haml
#your form code

#SalesController
def create
  @sale = Sale.new(params[:sale])
  if @sale.save
    format.js { render action: "create"}
  else
    format.js { render action: "new" }
  end
end

#sales/create.js.erb
#Here you hide a form and write something like "success".
#You can return "new sale" button (if you decide to remove it.)
```

Also, ajax callbacks are very useful in this situation. For example:

```
$('.your-remote-button').bind 'ajax:success', ->
  $(this).closest('div').fadeOut()
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Mikhail D

Comment: Im new to Rails, Jquery and Ajax but let me see if understand what you are saying. First i should make a new.js.erb file inside sales views folder to render the new sale form, then in the create action of sales controller i use only format.js right? and the ajax bit is to close the rendered div i guess. I will try it out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @user1350443, you are welcome. Yes, something like this. I am afraid that there is a lot of rails magic and you'll have to debug this code. The most important thing - look  at the AJAX request log if you have a trouble.

Comment: Ok i have tried the code to render the new sale form inside a div but is not working, i keep being redirected to the new_sale_apth instead of rendering the form inside the div, i have tried removing the format.html and format.json from the new sale action even removing the format.js from the new sale action as well, but when i do that the button doesnt do anything. I will edit my question to post my code.

Comment: @user1350443, your `link_to` is wrong: url params are mixed with others. Try this: `<%= link_to "Venta", new_sale_path(:cliente_id => cliente.id), :remote => true %>`. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Comment: Thanks for the link, it clears out a lot of doubts i have about links.
The link seems to work fine now, though it is not rendering the form yet. This is what says in my development log after i click the link:
"Started GET "/sales/new?cliente_id=9" for 10.0.2.2 at 2012-05-30 13:04:43 -0700
Processing by SalesController#new as JS
  Parameters: {"cliente_id"=>"9"}
Rendered sales/new.js.erb (220.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 295ms (Views: 284.8ms | ActiveRecord: 7.0ms)

So it should be working, but is not showing it, also there are no script errors in the chromium web debug thing.

Comment: You must have a `Rendered sales/_form.html.erb` in your log. It seems, your js file does not render the form. There are another one caveat: javascript console doesn't show errors in this case. Try to put `alert("test");` in the begin/end/etc of file.

Comment: Yeah it says "Rendered sales/_form.html.erb (39.5ms)
  Rendered sales/new.js.erb (252.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 325ms (Views: 316.0ms | ActiveRecord: 6.0ms)", but i tried the alert("message"); in the new.html.erb file and the alerts didnt show up at all, so there must be something wrong with my script

Comment: Indeed it was a problem in my new.js.erb file, when i erased the commented lines with the sign "#" it worked!, i think is because thats not the way to make comments in a .js file and so it was braking it. Anyway, this worked like a charm, thank you very mach Mikhail D   =)

Comment: Hi again, when i click in the save button it tries to redirect me to the sales view but it stays blank in the process and the html request sends a Status Code:406 Not Acceptable, though the sale gets saved in the database, do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: Have you added `remote: true` to the form? If yes, I have no more suggestions.

Comment: Yes i was missing the remote true in the form, sorry ill try harder before asking agian hehe.